# How to make the results of segmentby displayed for only the last row in each segment?

Tags: duplicates, dolphindb, segment

[image]

I have used `segmentby` to calculate the sum by group, with the third column of values as the segment. The above is the output table and in each segment, the results are returned in every row. But I only want the result to be displayed for the last row in each segment and no result for other rows. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isDuplicated` to remove duplicates and keep only the last duplicate values by specifying `keep=LAST`.

Refer to the following script:

```
x = 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2;
y = 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 2;
t = table(x,y);
select *, iif(isDuplicated(segment(y,false),LAST),NULL,sum(x)) as z from t context by segment(y,false)
```

[image]